# My go binaries end up in the src folder

Tags: go, liteide

My binaries end up in the src folder and I have no idea why. I want them to end up in gopath/bin (since that is the default? and since I don't want binaries on git). The packages end up in gopath/pkg with their binaries in their respective folder. I don't even know if this folder structure is considered good.

Gopath is set to the `gopath` folder on the `D:\` drive, and `gobin` is not set.

[image: go setup]

Comment: You use go install or go build?

Comment: "BuildAndRun" in LiteIDE. What else should I try?

Comment: I never use liteide but looks like it use go build here

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As you can see in the [liteIDE FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/golangide/wiki/FAQ):

> `<action id="BuildAndRun" img="blue/buildrun.png" key="Ctrl+R;Ctrl+F7" task="Build;Run"/>
>   <action id="Install" menu="Build" img="blue/install.png" key="Ctrl+F8" cmd="$(GO)" args="install $(INSTALLARGS)" save="all" output="true"/>`

- Build And Run is a `go build`.
- Install is `go install`

Only the latter would build your exe in `GOPATH/bin`.

Answer (score 33):

If you can pass a command line parameter to LiteIDE's `go build` instruction, you can do something like this;

`go build -o $GOPATH/bin/outputfile.exe source.go`